# Equivalent expression for "Show your true colors" in Portuguese

Tags: expressões, expressões-idiomáticas

In English the expression *show your true colors* meaning:

You show your true colours if you show what you're really like, or you reveal your true character.

Does there exist any equivalent expression in Portuguese (Europe/Brazilian)?

---

Em Inglês usamos a expressão *show your true colors* que significa:

Mostrar realmente quem você é ou revelar a seu verdadeiro caráter.

Existe alguma expressão equivalente em Português?

Comment: "Mostrar realmente quem você é ou revelar o seu verdadeiro caráter."

Comment: @JorgeB. te juro que não foi o googletradutor -- fui eu mesmo kk- obrigado

Comment: @JorgeB. No Brasil usamos "seu verdadeiro eu", em Portugal este também é o mais comum? Está me parece a resposta mais correta: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/492/8

Comment: Acho que não se usa muito isto aqui...

Comment: @JorgeB. Será que é algo regional? Conforme o user3397179 o termo é usado em Portugal. É uma daquelas perguntas que metade da resposta está correta e a outra metade está em outra resposta.

Comment: Eu acho que não se usa muito qualquer das expressões.

Answer (score 4):

The best option that comes to my mind is:

> Mostre sua verdadeira cara

That could be translated like: "Show me your true face" where "cara" is a colloquial way to say "rosto".

Other idiomatic expression linked to the same purpose is:

> Tire sua máscara

That could be translated like : "Take off your mask."

This two sentences are commonly used together so:

> Tire sua máscara, mostre-me sua verdadeira cara

is my bet to the better equivalent expression.

Comment: São duas boas opções.

Answer (score 3):

I have heard this from a song:

> *Mostra-me o teu **lado lunar*** (Rui Veloso, [Lado Lunar](http://letras.mus.br/rui-veloso/41674/)): show me your "moon" side

The intended meaning is:

> *mostra-me a tua **face oculta***: show me your hidden face

Which resembles the true colors of a person, without literally mentioning them.

### Edit

A [French dictionary translates the "true colors" expression](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/to-show-one-s-true-colours) to:

> *se montrer sous son vrai jour*

Which literally translated would be: show me as you are in one of your real (true) days... Therefore in Portuguese you could also deduce:

> *mostre(a)-me **como é(s) verdadeiramente** (num dos teus dias)*: show me how you truly are/behave

However, Portuguese prefer to use the "face", so:

> *mostra-me a sua/tua **verdadeira cara/face***: show me your true face

Comment: I'm not sure if is the same thing...

Comment: *"tua face oculta"* seems more common.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento: more common and more poetic, as it can relate to the dark side of the moon :)

Comment: @brasofilo All examples sounds like "poetic" (It may be just me) :)

Answer (score 2):

He ended up showing his true colors. **(Original)**

He ended up showing/revealing his true self. 
He ended up showing/revealing his true intentions. 
Maybe some day you'll see his true colors.

Ele acabou por mostrar/revelar o seu verdadeiro eu.  **(Portugal)** 
Ele acabou por mostrar/revelar a(s) sua(s) verdadeira(s) intenção/ões. 
Um dia irás perceber quem é que ele realmente é. 
<sup>**Literal-ish translation:** Some day you'll understand who he really is. *(His true intentions; How/who he really is)*</sup>

*(**Brazil:** [Same as in Portugal](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/453/equivalent-expression-for-show-your-true-colors-in-portuguese/492?noredirect=1#comment1020_492), I think.)*

Comment: *seu verdadeiro eu* - também é usado no Brasil, na verdade é o termo mais usado no Brasil